# Are there other similar Mandarin Chinese radio plays?

Tags: resources, practice, audio

1. I used to listened to this Buddhist stories radio play ([空中结缘](http://programme.rthk.hk/channel/radio/programme.php?name=pth/kongzhong)） some time ago. It's aired weekly by RTHK/香港电台 and apart from the recitations from Buddhist scriptures, I think the dialog parts are pretty good for learners of Chinese, the stories are entertaining and there are plenty of them, so I thought I would share the feed link with you:

http://podcast.rthk.hk/podcast/pchances.xml

(It also has a [Cantonese version](http://programme.rthk.hk/channel/radio/programme.php?name=radio5/chances), in case someone is interested).

2. There was another radio play podcast broadcast by a Singaporean radio station running under the title 麻达一郎 (Mada Yilang, a Japanese name), which was about a Japanese criminal police investigation, also a nice one. Unfortunately it seems to be completely removed from the website (xin.msn.com). Has anyone by any chance *heard of it or knows where to download it from* again? I would highly recommend it those who are intermediate learners of Mandarin， if only I still knew where the files are hosted.
3. Are there any good quality Mandarin language radio plays you know of and would recommend it to practice Chinese?

**

Answer (score 2):

Try 新闻酸菜馆

For some reasons, mainland Chinese do not have much existence on podcast, but you can find tons of fine broadcasts on another app, **荔枝FM** (you have to search in Chinese with that though.).